# Css image viewer is moving page on click

Tags: css, image, viewer

When I click in the tabs at the side, it changes the picture, which is what I want it to do, but it also moves the page so the view is at the top. I noticed this only happened when there was page content below as well, thats why in this example I have put a load of line breaks.

Here is a link of what my page looks like if you want a better example of what I mean:

dl.dropbox.com/u/8391091/Ebay%20page.html

The code I have put here is just of the image viewer (css, html)

```
            /* Setup Tabs */

            #view ul{

            margin-top: 0;
            background: black;
            width: 85px; /* Width of Tab Image */
            float: left;
            list-style: none;
            border-right:8px solid grey;
            }

            #view ul li{

            margin-left: -40px;
            margin-right: -40px;
            height:75px; /* Height of Tab Image */
            }

            /* Setup Tab so normal opacity is 40 and rollover is 100 */
            #view ul li a img{
            border: 0px;    
            /* for IE */
            -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)";
            filter:alpha(opacity=50);

            /* CSS3 standard */
            opacity:0.5;

            }

            /* Change Opacity to 100% on hover*/
            #view ul li a:hover img{

            /* for IE */
            -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
            filter:alpha(opacity=100);

            /* CSS3 standard */
            opacity: 1.0;
            }

            /* Places images to the right of the tabs,
            and hides non selected images */
            #images{

            width: 500px; 
            height: 300px; 
            overflow: hidden;  /* Hides the non selected images */
            float: left;
            }

            /* Square border around viewer*/
            #wrapper{
            outline-style: none;
            border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
            border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px 5px;
            width: 633px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 10px solid grey;
            margin: 0px auto;
            }
            </style>

            <div id="section1">
            <div id="view">
            <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- Tabs -->
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#image1" id="tab1"><img src="http://i1114.photobucket.com/albums/k536/outatimeoyster/IMG_4095.jpg?t=1312893965" width="125" height="75"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#image2" id="tab2"><img src="http://i1114.photobucket.com/albums/k536/outatimeoyster/IMG_4093.png?t=1312894058" width="125" height="75"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#image3" id="tab3"><img src="http://i1114.photobucket.com/albums/k536/outatimeoyster/IMG_4089.png?t=1312894246" width="125" height="75"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#image4" id="tab4"><img src="http://i1114.photobucket.com/albums/k536/outatimeoyster/Photo07-08-2011205730.jpg?t=1312894308" width="125"           height="75"/></a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Images -->
            <div id="images">
            <div><a name="image1"></a><img src="http://i1114.photobucket.com/albums/k536/outatimeoyster/IMG_4095.jpg?t=1312893965" width="500" height="300" /></div>
            <div><a name="image2"></a><img src="http://i1114.photobucket.com/albums/k536/outatimeoyster/IMG_4093.png?t=1312894058" width="500" height="300" /></div>
            <div><a name="image3"></a><img src="http://i1114.photobucket.com/albums/k536/outatimeoyster/IMG_4089.png?t=1312894246" width="500" height="300" /></div>
            <div><a name="image4"></a><img src="http://i1114.photobucket.com/albums/k536/outatimeoyster/Photo07-08-2011205730.jpg?t=1312894308" width="500" height="300" /></div>
            </div>
            </div>      
            </div>
            <p class="text" align="center">(Click tabs at side for larger picture)</p>      
            </div>

            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>

            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            More page content
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
```

Answer (score 1):

It uses fragment identifiers(in the url:" #image1 ") and it's the default behavior.When you use these for jump links, It brings the element with the id that's in the url at the top of the page.Now to fix that, I m not sure but I ll try right now!
What about this one instead?\
http://alt-web.com/DEMOS/CSS-Image-Viewer.shtml
You could just do a rollover and have a span with the big picture change it's visibility from hidden to visible. That's how you normally do it.You just have to change your code a bit and have all the big pictures stacked over each other instead of hidden with the overflow.

Comment: Do you know the code to fix it, and will my viewer look any different?

Comment: no.Instead of clicking on the pictures,users will only have to hover.

Answer (score 0):

```
a href="#viewer">
<img src="../Photo_Gallery/thumbs/pic1.jpg">
<span>
<img src="../Photo_Gallery/pic1.jpg">
<br>
   optional caption
</span>
</a>
```

so you put the main picture in a span.

```
.rollover li a span {
      visibility: hidden;
}
.rollover a:hover, .rollover a:hover span, .rollover a:active, .rollover a:active
span, .rollover a:focus, .rollover a:focus span {
      visibility: visible;
}
```

That's how they do it in the tutorial.So instead of having all your pictures in line and using overflow:hidden like you did.Put each one under its respective thumbnail than you have to position them on top of each other hidden.But the thing is,the way they do it, there's no picture showing on page load. So I ll try to find a way to fix that.